# How to make JavaScript affect only between specific tags

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript. in jquery mobile . i want it to only shows inside the this div . now when i run it, it doesn't show any styles or jquery. just shows the javascript.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
        CodeFile="phonedirectory.aspx.vb" Inherits="phonedirectory" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <div class="timeline" id="lists" data-role="content">
                   </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
            <center>
                <a href="Default.aspx">
                    <img src="Content/images/logo.png" /></a></center>
        </div>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        else {// code for IE6, IE5
                            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        xmlhttp.read
                        xmlhttp.open("GET", "xml.aspx", false);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

                        document.write("<ul id='employee' data-role='listview' data-filter='true'>");
                        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
                        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                            document.write("<li class='ui-screen-hidden'>")
                            document.write("<a href='info.aspx?ID=");
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("'>")
                            document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                            document.write("</a></li>");
                        }
                        document.write("</ul>");


                </script>
                </div>
```

Comment: I tried to do var txt = document.getElementById('lists');
but i think i did it wrong,

Comment: use the DOM building functions like createElement and appendChild, not document.write.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't close the script tag.

Secondly, if you're writing JavaScript in an HTML page, you should use single quotes to avoid clashing with the double quotes used for HTML markup, or escape your double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply .i have 
            </script> but i forgot to copy it, i am writing using asp.net. do i have to use single quotes.

Comment: What kind of "double quotes used for HTML markup" do you mean?

Comment: You can try copying the JS into a separate file to see if it's a conflict with the page.

Comment: @EMMERICH agreed - inline scripts are problematic

Comment: Also, your line `xmlhttp.read` does nothing. Are you missing brackets?

Comment: And lastly, because the requests are asynchronous, you need to place the code you want to run when it completes inside a function on the `onsuccess` property. When you do `xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML`, the server hasn't returned with your result. It would be:
`xmlhttp.onsuccess = function() { xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML }`

Comment: if i copy the js into  a separate file how can i target this div only.